# Kotlin native; compilation failed: cannot run msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-clang-llvm-lld-compiler_rt-8.0.1/bin/clang++

Tags: kotlin, windows-7-x64, clang++, kotlin-native

I use `Windows 7` and followed [Get started with Kotlin/Native using the command-line compiler](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-command-line-compiler.html), downloaded [kotlin-native-windows-1.5.10.zip](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/download/v1.5.10/kotlin-native-windows-1.5.10.zip) and added its `bin` to the `PATH` of system. But when I try `kotlinc-native hello.kt -o hello`, get this error:

```
error: compilation failed: Cannot run program "C:\Users\<user-name>\.konan\dependencies\msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-clang-llvm-lld-compiler_rt-8.0.1/bin/clang++": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

What is the problem and how I can solve that?

**Edit:**

It seems the problem is caused by `clang++.exe`which is in

```
C:\Users\<user-name>\.konan\dependencies\msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-clang-llvm-lld-compiler_rt-8.0.1/bin/
```

because when I try to run it, I get this error:

```
clang++ is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: Try creating Kotlin/Native project as a Gradle project (with [IntelliJ IDEA wizard](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-get-started.html)). It works on my Win7 machine. Probably instructions about building with the command-line compiler are incomplete (a lot of things happens during Gradle build)

Comment: Are you running `kotlinc-native` or `kotlinc-native.bat`? It might be important in this case.

Comment: Try to run it with an additional `-verbose` option. What will be the output?

Comment: @МихаилНафталь `-verbose` does not add any other information.

Comment: Are you sure you are running 64-bit OS? What is the result of `wmic os get osarchitecture` command in the console?

Comment: I could compile `kotlinc-native hello.kt -o hello` just fine (creates `hello.exe`), but I am on Windows 10. Message _not a valid Win32 application_ seems to suggest that your operating system is 32-bit rather than 64-bit, but I could be wrong ...(?) ~ * ~ Not an answer to your question, but – given the problems you face – how about "compiling" and "running" via Java instead: `kotlinc hello.kt -include-runtime -d hello.jar` (creates `hello.jar`; run as `java -jar hello.jar`)? – If yes, you would have to use the `kotlin-compiler-1.x.xx.zip` at https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/latest.